# How to replicate Alteryx logic of "MultiRow" Transfromation in Azure Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a tool in Alteryx(ETL Tool) where there is a transformation called "Multi Row" Which does the following :
Tool configuration:

Explaination of what its doing:
If the col has null ,its taking THE VALUE BEHIND ONE ROW .As "2012" is behind every null ,its filling up everything with "2012".

How to achieve this in Azure Data Flow ?
[image]

input data :[image]

output data :[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Window transformation** in dataflow to fill the null values with the previous value. I reproduced with sample input data and below is the approach.

- Input data is taken like this.
  [image]
- Derived column is added with a dummy column named dummy and value is `1` for all rows.

[image]

- Surrogate key is created for sort column in windows transformation. (If you have any field for sorting, use that in the Windows transformation.)

Surrogate key settings:

```
Key name: sk 
Start value: 1
Step value: 1
```

[image]

- Windows transformation is taken and settings is given as

```
1. over: dummy
2. sort:  sk ascending
3. Range by : unbounded
4. windows column: year = coalesce(year, last(year, true()))
```

[image: gifwindowstransformation]

**Result:**

[image]

You can use select transformation and select only the required fields and discard the dummy fields.

Comment: last() gives me the previous row value ,but in case if I want Previous 2nd row or third row values in the current just like ROWS BEHIND AFTER in SQL .Can we achieve this same scenario with lag() function ?

Comment: **last() gives me the previous row value** - For this requirement last() function is enough since it replaces the null value in sequential order.

Comment: **if I want Previous 2nd row or third row values** - Yes you can use [lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#lag) function to get this.

Comment: When i use coalease(year,lag(year,1,0)) ,i will not get the same result because in last there is a flag=true() which ignores nulls , here in lag we dont have any.

Comment: last is going for last nonNull value ,how to go to 1 row after , lead and lag are not working as expected .

Comment: if I do coalease(year,lag/lead(year,1,0) , I will not get the same result as coalease(year,last(year,true()). Can you help here to achieve this

Comment: `coaleasce(year,lag(year,1,0))` - What do you get as output? Expression is correct only.

Comment: Am getting like 2012 ,2012 in the first 2 rows , rest all are null . Again  2013 2013  rest are all null.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252827/discussion-between-surya-teja532-and-aswin).

Comment: Did you get anything on this ?